# Why do we need to handle blossoms when finding maximum matchings?

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching

We know the standard algorithm for finding maximum matching in general graph.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

What I am trying to understand is that what is the need to handle blossom separately?

I think finding augmenting path and complementing it is enough. It works with odd cycle as well.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/106528/755

Comment: It is not answered yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you can form a maximum matching by using the following general algorithm:

1. If such a path exists, augment along that path to increase the size of the matching by one. Repeat.
2. If no such path exists, your matching is maximum and you're done.

The challenge, though, is determining whether such an augmenting path exists in the graph. With a small graph it might not be all that hard to find a path, but as the graphs get larger and larger and the partial matchings increase in size it can become pretty challenging. Brute-force searching through all the possible paths is not feasible at this scale.

In the case where the graph is bipartite (there are no odd-length cycles), there are nice algorithms that do this that are based on a modification of breadth-first or depth-first search. They work nicely because you can classify nodes as being either at an odd or even distance from a start node. With odd cycles, this breaks down, and these simple algorithms don't work.

The reason the blossom algorithm exists - and the reason why blossoms are there in the first place - is that they provide a mechanism for efficiently searching the graph for augmenting paths even in the presence of blossoms. The intuition is that every time you see a blossom, you can contract it down to a point in a way that doesn't mess up your ability to find augmenting paths. Contracting an odd cycle reduces the size of the graph, and through recursion you'll either end a graph where it's easy to find an augmenting path or you'll find that there aren't any.

So in a sense, the reason we use blossoms is that it enables us to efficiently (in polynomial time) check whether augmenting paths exist and, if so, find them and augment across them.